# I want to run my task of Project A from Project B using celery. Both of them have different code base. Is it possible to do so?

Tags: python, celery, django-celery, celery-task

I am using celery in both the projects. Redis is used as a broker and backend. Suppose project A has task

```
@shared_task()
def add(x,y):
  return x+y
```

Now I want to send this task in Project B and execute it there. Is there any possible way to do so?

Both the project has configuration like this

```
from celery import Celery
app = Celery('task',broker='redis://localhost:6379/1',backend='rpc://')
```

Comment: I have been able to send the task from Project A to Project B using app.send_task('task_name')

But every alternate time I get error. Any possible solution to this. Error message is like this

`The full contents of the message body was:
'[["math"], {}, {"callbacks": null, "errbacks": null, "chain": null, "chord": null}]' (83b)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pkg/Documents/teacher/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/worker/consumer/consumer.py", line 581, in on_task_received
    strategy = strategies[type_]
KeyError: 'studata.tasks.total_marks'`